# Map of map in salesforce

Tags: custom-object, map, id

How to populate values into this map? There are three objects named `job__c`, `employee__c` and a junction object between `job__c` and `employee__c` named `JobEmployeeJunction__c´. I want the list of employees related to a job.

```
Map<Id,Map<Id,Employee__c>> mapOfIdToJunctionObjectToEmployee = new Map<Id,Map<Id,Employee__c>>();
For(JobEmployeeJunction__c jobEmpJunction : jobEmployeeJunctionList){
  For(Job__c jobVar : jobList){
    if(!mapOfIdToJunctionObjectToEmployee.keySet().contains(jobVar.id,jobEmpJunction.Employee__c)){
      mapOfIdToJunctionObjectToEmployee.put(jobVar.id,jobEmpJunction.Employee__c, new Employee__c());
    }
    mapOfIdToJunctionObjectToEmployee.get(jobVar.id).add(jobEmpJunction);
  }
}
```

Comment: jobList = [Select Client__c,Client_Type__c,Amount_without_discount__c,Discount__c,Due_Amount__c,End_Date__c,Number_of_booking_days__c,Paid_Amount__c,Recurrences__c,Start_Date__c,Status__c,Type_of_job__c,Amount_to_be_paid__c from job__c where id IN :jobId];         jobEmployeeJunctionList = [Select Employee__c,Job__c,Amount_Paid_By_Client__c,Sallary_For_Employee__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c from JobEmployeeJunction__c where Job__c IN :jobId];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to form the query/perform this task depending how you want to map to be.

According to your question you want all employees listed for each Jobs i.e Job Ids I assume. So below is a sample code which will form a Map of Job Ids to a list of employees who have applied for it.

The SOQL query which I used will fetch all the Employees in the system and the inner query will fetch all the associated Jobs to each employees. Next, I loop through each Employee's associated jobs and populate the Job Id to Employees map.

```
Map<Id, List<Employee__c>> mapOfJobIdToEmployees = new Map<Id, List<Employee__c>>();
for(employee__c emp : [select Id, (Select Id, job__c from JobEmployeeJunctions__r)  from employee__c])
{
    for(JobEmployeeJunction junctionRec : emp.JobEmployeeJunctions__r)
    {
        if(mapOfJobIdToEmployees.containsKey(junctionRec.job__c))
        {
            mapOfJobIdToEmployees.get(junctionRec.job__c).add(emp);
        }
        else
        {
            mapOfJobIdToEmployees.put(junctionRec.job__c, new List<Employee__c>{emp});
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a complicated map of map in your scenario. I suggest to you to use the Query child-to-parent relationships in soql [(link to SFDC docs)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) to query the junction object and get all the information you need from the related object (Job__c / Employee__c )

```
    List<JobEmployeeJunction__c> jobEmployeeJunctionList = [Select Employee__c,Job__c,Amount_Paid_By_Client__c,Sallary_For_Empl‌​oyee__c,Start_Date__‌​c,End_Date__c,Job__r.Client__c,Job__r.Client_Type__c,Job__r.Amount_without_discount__c,Job__r.Discount‌​__c,Job__r.Due_Amount__c,Job__r.En‌​d_Date__c,Job__r.Number_of_‌​booking_days__c,Job__r.Paid‌​_Amount__c,Job__r.Recurrenc‌​es__c,Job__r.Start_Date__c,Job__r.‌​Status__c,Job__r.Type_of_jo‌​b__c,Job__r.Amount_to_be_pa‌​id__c from JobEmployeeJunction__c where Job__c IN :jobId]; 

    Map<Id,List<Id>> mapOfIdJobToEmployeeIdList = Map<Id,List<Id>>();
    for(JobEmployeeJunction__c jobEmpJunction : jobEmployeeJunctionList){
        List<Id> employeeIdList;
        if(!mapOfIdJobToEmployeeList.containsKey(jobEmpJunction.Job__c)){
            //There is no key: Instantiate a new list
            employeeIdList = new List<Id>();
        }else{
            //There is a Key in the map: a list is already instantiated
            employeeIdList = mapOfIdJobToEmployeeList.get(jobEmpJunction.Job__c);


    }
        //add the Id of the employee
        employeeList.add(jobEmpJunction.Employee__c);
        mapOfIdJobToEmployeeList.put(jobEmpJunction.Job__c, employeeIdList);
    }
```